# Linear independence over an extension

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

I'm working with the extension $k(p):k(p^n)$

where p is an indeterminate.

I'm trying to show that ${1,p,p^2,...,p^{n-1}}$ is linearly independent on $k(p^n)$

I started by assuming they're linearly dependent and then trying to arrive at a contradiction using the shortest relation of dependence i.e $a_0+a_1p+...+a_mp^m=0$ where all $a_i \neq 0$ and $m\leq n-1$

But haven't been able to progress, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p$ is a root of the polynomial $f=X^n-p^n$. It suffices to prove that this polynomial is irreducible over $k(p^n)$ since then $[k(p):k(p^n)]=n$. By Gauss's lemma, $f$ is irreducible over $k(p^n)$ if and only if it is such over $k[p^n]$; and this follows from Eisenstein's criterion because $p^n$ is irreducible over $k[p^n]$.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm proving this linear independence to then prove that          $[k(p):k(p^n)]=n$ sorry for not making that clear in the question

Comment: Well, after having proved that $f$ is irreducible over the field $k(p^n)$ it follows that $1, \ldots, p^{n-1}$ are linearly independent over $k(p^n)$.

Comment: I don't see why $p^n$ is irreducible over $k(p^n)$, I'm sure it's something straight forward I am missing

Comment: @TheProblem Use Eisenstein criterion to prove that

Comment: @dragoboy I'm sure you're correct, but isn't Eisenstein with prime numbers?

Comment: As stated above, the irreducibility of $p^n$ in $k(p^n)$ is equivalent to the irreducibility over $k[p^n]$. But elements in $k[p^n]$ are of the form $g(p^n)$ with $g \in k[X]$. In particular, the degree of $g(p^n)$ is equal to $n \cdot \text{deg}(g)$. Now use that the degree of the product of two polynomials over an integral domain is the sum of the degrees.

Comment: No, its true form any ring and its primes

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion works over UFDs. And in such rings an element is prime iff it is irreducible.

Comment: Sorry could you please state what the notation $k[p^n]$ means as opposed to $k(p^n)$

Comment: $k[p^n]=\{g(p^n) \vert g(X) \in k[X] \}$, and $k(p^n)$ is the quotient field of that ring, i.e. $k(p^n)=\{ g(p^n)/f(p^n) \vert g(X),f(X) \in k[X], f \neq 0\}$.

Comment: Okay, thank you that helps a great deal. So the fact f is irreducible implies that we have linear independence, but does that implication rely on knowing the degree of the extension is equal to n?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Consider the evaluating homomorphism $k(p^n)[X] \to k(p)$. Since $f$ is irreducible, the kernel of this homomorphism is the ideal generated by $f$. If now $1, \ldots, p^{n-1}$ are linearly independent over $k(p^n)$, then there exists a polynomial $0 \neq g$ in $k(p^n)[X]$ of degree $n-1$ with $p$ as a root, i.e. $g \in (f)$, which is impossible since $f$ cannot divide $g$ for reasons of degree.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to write. But, Let $g(p)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f_i(p^n)p^i$. Clearly $g$ has a non zero leading term, so its never zero

Comment: What does $f_i$ represent?

Comment: As usual, $f_i(p^n) \in k(p^n)$

Comment: why do we know the leading term isn't zero?

Comment: That's why I said I don't know how to write it properly, Suppose it is zero,  expand everything. Let $nk+i$ be the maximum degree you see, its coefficient is not zero, so you must get another one $p^{nk+i}$ from somewhere else, which we can't find. You convince yourself why we can't